# How to execute a command when a value in Firebase Database change?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to execute a command every time data in Firebase-Database is changed?

Comment: There is an entire SDK dedicated to interacting with the Firebase Database from your Android app. I highly recommend that you start with the documentation for that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/. If you're more a do-er than a reader, there's also an Android codelab here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/#codelabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `ValueEventListener` with the `onDataChange` event callback [as specified here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events). With that you access the `dataSnapshot` argument and determine the appropriate action to take. Example from the documentation:

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```